# sql trigger not work as expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

when one row is added to the customer table it should:

- copy to the other table called new_customer table
- delete the row in customer table.

In customer table has only one field that is Phone number.

This field should be copy into the new customer table and should be deleted from the customer table.

please can anyone tell me what's wrong with this trigger.....

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_cus
ON customer
FOR update AS
   IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 1) > 0
      BEGIN

      INSERT INTO new_customer
         (Phone number
            )
         SELECT 'NEW',
            ins.Phone number
         FROM inserted ins

         SELECT 'OLD', 
            del.Phone number
         FROM deleted del

   END
```

Comment: Doesn't look like valid SQL at all... What is it that you're trying to do? an audit log?

Comment: Is this really MySQL? I thought `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` was a SQL Server-ism.

Comment: Questions: Is the field really "Phone number" with a space? is "Phone number" a unique key in both tables? Is this code you've tried above: real column names, real table names?

Answer (score 2):

My guess

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_cus
ON customer
FOR update AS
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
   BEGIN

      INSERT INTO new_customer ([Phone number])
         SELECT 'NEW', ins.[Phone number]
         FROM inserted ins

      DELETE customer WHERE
         [Phone number] IN (SELECT [Phone number] FROM deleted)

   END
```

Comment: Surely has to be for Inserted as well?  based on his explanaition as far as I can read it?  You also still have his attempt to insert two values into one named field?

Comment: @Dems: I'm not sure. I think OP wants to swap a value from one table to another (INSTEAD OF triiger?)  You could be right though.

Comment: I've made my attempt at helping, now I'm off for a shower, a BBQ and a football match.  Good luck on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You want behaviour for an INSERT but have defined the trigger for an UPDATE.

Your INSERT specifies one field, but you try to insert 2 values.

You state that you want to DELETE a record from customer, but don't have a DELETE statement.

I've refrained from writing a different trigger for you because I'm not actually 100% certain what you are trying to achieve.

Could you give examples, including what the various tables should look like before and after different actions?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_cus
ON customer
FOR insert AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO new_customer (name, id)
  SELECT name, id
  FROM inserted

  DELETE customer WHERE
  id IN (SELECT id FROM deleted)
  -- This assumes id is Unique, but as the table should normally be empty, that's fine.

END
```

Comment: @Denis Please find below scenario 1.insert value to customer1 table(eg:- insert into customer1(name,id) values("linda",1234);) 2.trigger should delete what I entered in the customer1 table and enter same details to customer2 table(customer1 table will be empty all the time) Thank you very much for your corporation.

Comment: gbn's answer modified based on your comment.