# background process using thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to continuously check a table in the database to see whether a new row has been added to  it. This runs as a back ground process. I think a thread should be used for this task. but I have no idea how to write the code. Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Your question is a bit over-general in that to answer it well would require us to write a full tutorial. Rather than us do that, have you checked the threading tutorials that already exist? If so, what *specifically* are you confused about? A general rule here is that the more specific the question usually the more specific (and helpful) the answer.

Comment: There are tons of examples for threads, take this to start with: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/BasicThread.html . Also, look at the docs for threads: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html .

Comment: Look at `java.util.Timer` (and related `TimerTask`); it executes periodic tasks.

Comment: @toto there's only 1 thread for all timers. Network operations can take a long time, and could disrupt other tasks. I think I'd use a dedicated single threaded executor for this, each check scheduling the next.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not really giving us much to go on here.

You might find it easier to use a [database trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger), which will fire some code whenever a specified action occurs (e.g. insertion of new data). You will need to look up details for your specific database.

I just realised that you have probably already tried to use triggers and failed: [sql trigger not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162159/sql-trigger-not-work-as-expected). Either approach will work, but I would prefer keeping everything in the DB and avoiding external processes if possible.

What should happen if an insert occurs but your process has died for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle can now communicate to Java via listener. So if you register for some event, your Java listener will receive that event from the database.